# Failure to sync web application

Tags: 2010, administration

We recently updated some admin passwords and of course this affected our SharePoint 2010 environment. however, we changed the password back to the original but we are still receiving this error. Is this related?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Portal Server
Date:          30/08/2016 12:00:11
Event ID:      5555
Task Category: User Profiles
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      
User:          ****\spfarmservice
Computer:      **************
Description:
Failure trying to synch web application d3b0608c-1bd7-4c67-9bfc-ac5d7da5d62a, ContentDB 46b69c1f-2c7a-4cf6-aa95-31e9921300a5  Exception message was System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken.GetCurrentChange(SqlSession session, Int64& changeNumber, DateTime& changeTime)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken..ctor(SPContentDatabase db)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.get_CurrentChangeToken()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SynchContentDB()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.ULS.SendWatsonOnExceptionTag(UInt32 tagID, ULSCatBase categoryID, String output, Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Portal Server" Guid="{8B3DDD3D-2B09-4669-BF81-E2D6921FEEEA}" />
    <EventID>5555</EventID>
    <Version>14</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>8</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-08-30T11:00:11.465982000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>807562</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{82A4695D-CF53-4089-B6AA-F312F1A123F4}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="13140" ThreadID="12544" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1937380958-2102339226-1848903544-32507" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="string0">Failure trying to synch web application d3b0608c-1bd7-4c67-9bfc-ac5d7da5d62a, ContentDB 46b69c1f-2c7a-4cf6-aa95-31e9921300a5</Data>
    <Data Name="string1">System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken.GetCurrentChange(SqlSession session, Int64&amp; changeNumber, DateTime&amp; changeTime)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken..ctor(SPContentDatabase db)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.get_CurrentChangeToken()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SynchContentDB()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.ULS.SendWatsonOnExceptionTag(UInt32 tagID, ULSCatBase categoryID, String output, Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Cheers.

UPDATE
Found this article on Microsoft Support.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771665

UPDATE 2

We seem to not be able to access some sub sites on SP2010 since updating password of admin account but when reverting back has not fixed the issue. Not all sub sites are accessible but some still are. It is not a consistent issue but definitely seems related to updating user account password.

Comment: that article fix the issue?

Comment: In all honesty, this article does not seem to relate with the overall issue. WE are also having issues with certain sub sites of a sp2010 site not working but other sites collections are working. It seems inconsistent, this was an error we became aware of as it came up as this error began.

Comment: So basically you change the password for farm admin account?

Comment: A member the team did. We reverted the password back but that didn't work which then lead to confusion of errors etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience, when ever you change the password do the following things.

- Do the IIS reset on all servers in Farm and after that perform the test
- if you face the issue then run [Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607627.aspx), it will help to sync the password across all components and test after it.
- in some cases you have to clear the Config Cache on the server to remove the old password from cache.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go. Will update on results once done.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the password was changed for our admin account that was running the services. The services needed to be stopped and restarted to input the new passwords for the services that were being run by the updated account. Restarted all servers in the SP Farm and all is back up and running.

Thanks for the input and help.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the iis and try it.

open command prompt(Run as administrator) -> type iisreset

Comment: Would this be done just on the web front end or on all SharePoint 2010 Servers?

Comment: sharepoint 2010 servers